# How to instruct automapper to ignore nested entity when they are null

Tags: automapper

I'm using Automapper to automatically flatten objects using naming conventions

These are my Entities

```
class Student 
{
   string Name;
   Address Address;
}
class Address
{
   string Street;
   string City;
}
```

a student can have an address or not:

```
student1 = new Student {Name= "Rob", Address = new Address { Street = "my address", City = "Milan" }};
student2 = new Student {Name= "Tom" };
```

this is my DTO

```
class Student 
{
   string Name;
   string AddressStreet;
}
```

this is my mapping profile:

```
CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>();
```

mapping the first student works fine, but mapping the second

```
studentdto2 = _mapper.Map<Student, StudentDTO>(student2);
```

gives me a NullReference Exception

question: how to instruct automapper that the Student.Address property is optional and to not map it when it's null?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Automapper version which you are using. This issue will not happen in the latest automapper version(v 5.1.l). You can switch to the latest version and see if the same code works